# Stop recording if user stop speaking using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

Anyone have idea how to stop audio recording if user stop speaking while recording.

I am working on recording functionality in swift 4.0 and I have use  **AVAudioRecorder** for voice recording.

If anyone have source code for auto stop recording without using **NSTimer** please comment your suggestions.

Comment: Just looked at documentation and I see a section for `Using Audio Level Metering`. I haven't done it, but perhaps you could ensure audio metering is enabled and monitor the averagePower(forChannel) as the trigger to stop recording. You'd probably have to use `Timer` at some point and pick a threshold for silence duration. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder

Comment: I have tried this way, but I cant able to implement it. Do you have Idea about that, how to integrate it?

Comment: Haven't worked with the class much. This looks pretty recent and discusses getting decibels http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/04/15/swift-how-to-get-decibels/